# Does the order of items in DbSet match the order of rows in the database table in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

For example I have a **Postgres** database with table *Clients* where primary keys are **INT** and rows are naturally sorted by ascending of **Id**s. And I have **.Net Core** application with **Entity Framework Core** as ORM and **Npgsql** as data provider. So main questions:

1. Does order of items in returned collection of this listing will always match order of rows in original table in Database?

```
    var clients = context.Clients.ToList();
```

2. Does *Take()* applied to *DbSet* without *OrderBy()* will always return items from the begin of table in correct order?
3. Does *Skip()* applied to *DbSet* without *OrderBy()* will always skip items from the begin of table in correct order?
4. Are these listings are equal?

```
    var clients = context.Clients
        .Skip(10)
        .Take(5)
        .ToList();
```

```
    var clients = context.Clients
        .OrderBy(c => c.Id)
        .Skip(10)
        .Take(5)
        .ToList();
```

5. Do I have to always use *OderBy()* in expressions with *Skip()* and *Take()* when I want to paginate table?
6. Is all this behavior determined by the framework or by the data provider? For example, will these things be the same in **MSSQL**, **Postgres** and **MySql**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inherent order in the table, they may be physically stored in order of the clustered index, but the engine may return them to you in any order it sees fit to achieve performance and/or consistency unless you specify a sort order.

The original spec ([http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt)) says:

> If an order by clause is not specified, then the ordering of the
> rows of Q is implementation-dependent.

You should not rely on implementation-dependent details, as they are prone to change.

So basically Yes - you must specify an order. No they are not the same. Yes you need an orderby to use skip or take. And it is determined by BOTH the provider and framework, neither of which can be relied upon to stay this way, **even in between runs on the same version**. Just because you get the results in the order you expect a number of times, doesn't mean that will continue to happen.